# asp mvc обновить элементы на странице

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Изучаю asp, никак не могу найти правильный путь для реализации такой фичи:

На странице есть несколько div с данными и при нажатии на кнопку нужно передать в них актуальные данные(а для них создать сложную html разметку) без перезагрузки страницы.

---

**Пример**:

На странице есть корзина, она отображает количество товаров в ней их общую цену, и в раскрывающемся списке 3 последних товара.  Разметка корзины расположена на **_Layout.cshtml** .  корзина(html код) должна заполнится при загрузке странице и если нажата кнопка "добавить продукт". И без перезагрузки страницы.

**Проблема**: цена, количество и список, это все разные блоки(нельзя просто вернуть весь их общий html  ), и прежде чем вставить в них данные их нужно найти на странице.
Я пробовал сделать так:

1. Создал отдельную js функцию, вызывал ее где нужно, а в ней ajax получал данные и формировал html .

```js
function SmallCartUpdate() {

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "Carts/SmallCart",
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result) {


      $("#SmallCartCount").text(result.count);
      $("#SmallCartPrice").text(result.price);



      var productList = '';
      $.each(result.lastAdded, function(index, item) {
        productList += '<li > <a href="#">' + item.Product.Title + '</a></li >';
      })

      $("#SmallCartList").html(productList);

    },

  });
}
```

Но так не удобно создавать html для списка, я хочу сделать более сложную структуру. И нет доступа к Razor.

2. Вызывать метод контролера и вернуть PartialView и уже в нем найти блоки и вставлять в них данные.

```js
@ {
  var productList = ViewData.Eval("lastAdded") as List < ShopStore.Models.Cart > ;
}

@foreach(var item in @productList) { 
  <li > < a href = "#" > +@item.Product.Title + < /a></li >
  }

<script type = "text/javascript" >
  $("#SmallCartCount").text(ViewData.Eval("count"));
  $("#SmallCartPrice").text(ViewData.Eval("price"));
</script>
```

Тут js не работает, к тому же не ясно как мне поместить  foreach который формирует список в  $("#SmallCartList").text());

**Вопрос**: как реализуется данный функционал?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Частичное представление:

```
@{
  var productList = ViewData.Eval("lastAdded") as List<ShopStore.Models.Cart>; 
}

@foreach(var item in @productList) { 
  <li > < a href = "#" > +@item.Product.Title + < /a></li >
}

<input type="hidden" class="SmallCartCount" value="@ViewData.Eval("count")" />
<input type="hidden" class="SmallCartPrice" value="@ViewData.Eval("price")" />
```

Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "Carts/SmallCart",
  dataType: "html",
  success: function(result) {
    $("#SmallCartList").html(result);
    $("#SmallCartCount").text($("#SmallCartList .SmallCartCount").val());
    $("#SmallCartPrice").text($("#SmallCartList .SmallCartPrice").val());
  }
});
```